# storing files on iCloud and distributing them to all app users

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building a iOS 5.1 app using storyboard. this app contains a table view. My idea was to add an "add" button to my title bar, in the table view. When a user clicks on the add, a simple document editor I need to build (like keynote or pages) will open. when the user clicks on the save button, the file will be uploaded possibly on I cloud, and all other users of the application will be able to access it, from a downloads tab, download it, and add it to their own app (a sort of file sharing via iCloud). Is it possible to do something like that? How can I do it? Can I do it using iCloud, or do i need to build my own database?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should try to use this:

```
NSURL *urlToShare = ...; NSDate *date;
NSError *error;
NSURL *sharedURL =
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForPublishingUbiquitousItemAtURL:urlToShare
                                                         expirationDate:&date
                                                                  error:&error];
```

Thats from CS193p lessons. This code will help you to share files between different iCloud Accounts.

But remember that "Only files (not directories) maybe exported in this way.
The URL points to a copy of the file (so it is a read-only sharing mechanism)."

Hope this helps!

Comment: so, i just run this code with -IBAction from my button, and the file is uploaded on the iCloud server' AND THEN HOW CAN users download the shared file?

Comment: You can store these shared links in JSON file on some server (maybe Dropbox or smth like this), for example, and download/parse it in your app to obtain list of links.

Comment: Since you mentioned dropbox,  decided to use dropbox instead of iCloud. Now everything is ok, but I have the same problem for iCloud. The files are uploaded but not shared between all app users. I heard about a copy-ref thing, but do I need to create a server to use it?? (XML)?